# EJB abstract entity causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

In my ejb project I defined an abstract entity class called DataObjectEntity.java, and have all entities extend this class. The purpose is such that common fields can be reused and logging of activities in the system can be easier.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class DataObjectEntity implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Transient
  protected Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private PersonEntity createdBy;
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date createdAt;
  private PersonEntity lastModifiedBy;
  @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
  private Date lastModifiedAt;
  private boolean archived;

  public DataObjectEntity() {
    createdAt = new Date();
    lastModifiedAt = new Date();
    archived = false;
  }

  public DataObjectEntity(PersonEntity createdBy) {
    this();
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.lastModifiedBy = createdBy;       
  }

  public void modified(PersonEntity modifiedBy){
    this.lastModifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    this.lastModifiedAt = new Date();
    log.info("Object " + id + " modified by " + modifiedBy.getName());
  }

  public void created(PersonEntity createdBy){
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.lastModifiedBy = createdBy;
    log.info("Object " + id + " created by " + createdBy.getName());
  }

  //getters and setters
}
```

Then I used netbeans' built-in feature to generate JSF pages from entity classes. Everything was fine. I could run the project just fine.

But after adding a new entity, I got this NoClassDefFoundError for the super class entity when trying to deploy. The new entity was really simple with a 1-1 relationship defined with one of the pre-existing entity class. I tried everything I could think of: clean&build, restarting glassfish, dropping all tables, generating JSF for the new entity class though I don't need it... But nothing worked.

Eventually I deleted my new entity and only left some changes on the existing backing beans. And the error still persists. I even checked out a fresh working copy to apply the same changes to the backing beans - turned out that copy deploys fine. One of my teammates is getting exactly the same error when he tries to add a new entity. Any idea what might be the cause?

```
WARNING: entity/DataObjectEntity_
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: entity/DataObjectEntity_
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1486)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObjectToClass(ConversionManager.java:438)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.helper.ConversionManager.convertObject(ConversionManager.java:141)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourcePlatform.convertObject(DatasourcePlatform.java:160)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initializeCanonicalMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2552)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.getMetamodel(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2531)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:484)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getDatabaseSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:188)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:277)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:290)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:268)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.doJava2DB(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:373)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:435)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:483)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:465)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:386)
at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:453)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: entity.DataObjectEntity_
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
... 53 more
```

The persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyProject-warPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/myprojectdb</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Update:** My teammate found a very strange but promising way to fix this: rename the entity java file that reports the NoClassDefFoundError to .class. Wait for glassfish to compile and report errors. Then change it back to .java. Wait for glassfish to compile again then clean and build, deploy. Works every time.

Comment: Do you have any integration tests? if yes are they passing.Paste your persistence.xml. I will suggest create a test application with this class and if you have that error paste complete code from the test app here. Really hard to say anything from what you have posted.

Comment: I mysteriously "solved" the issue by adding `createdBy = null; lastModifiedBy = null;` in the default constructor of the DataObjectEntity class. Why?!

Comment: something to do with JPA2 metamodel classes probably (the ones with the "_" suffix), and that they need generating. After all that is what is referred to in the message. Why your chosen JPA implementation has a problem with that class not being there is something else ...

Comment: From your response I noticed you have two instances of 'PersonEntity' which is supposedly a subclass of this godclass 'DataObjectEntity' is that right ????

Comment: That's right. Would that be a problem? Circular reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception say the class entity/DataObjectEntity_ not DataObjectEntity, note the "_".

This is a JPA2 metamodel class that is only used for the type safe version of the Criteria API.  It is not required, and should not cause any issues.  Does you application still run successfully?

These model classes are optional and normally not needed, so missing them should not be causing any issue.  They are generated only at compile time, either by your IDE, or by the EclipseLinkk meta-model generator that has to be hooked up to your build process.

You change to resolve the issue make no sense, seems like you may have just had some compile issue with your IDE.

Comment: I'm using netbeans. I haven't seen the same problem since but my other teammates have. On some other classes though, like PersonEntity which is a subclass of DataObjectEntity and also the superclass of CustomerEntity and SystemUserEntity... And according to him, he did nothing but repeatedly cleaned, built, deployed and restarted Netbeans to eventually make the problem go away...